# Cannot connect to Azure Cloud Service from my Azure Website with Virtual IP?

Tags: azure, networking, ip, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure Website with virtual IP (ip based SSL), however, in my cloudservice I have to specify the address of my website to whitelist. Somehow I think I'm missing the obvious here since I cannot connect to my webservice when I deny all BUT my website. If I remove the Deny All -rule I can connect fine.

I now have, which wont work:

```
<AccessControl name="accessRestriction">      
    <Rule action="permit" description="permit-site" order="1" remoteSubnet="VIRTUALIPADDRESS/32" />
    <Rule action="deny" description="deny-public" order="2" remoteSubnet="0.0.0.0/0" />
  </AccessControl>
</AccessControls>
```

**EDIT**:
my website cannot connect to the webservice.***(Unable to connect to the remote server)***

**EDIT2:**
In my intellitrace log I can see that indeed the website is trying to gain access but is blocked
'Requested registry access is not allowed.'
Side note: If I add a permit-rule for my local home IP I CAN reach the webservice if my run my website locally (and connect from home).

2nd, off-topic question, In a lot of tutorials I see people using 'Order=100' and, 200 and then 300, instead of just using 1,2,3, why 3 digits? **(answered)**

**EDIT3:** both website and service are now https, still no connection possible with ACL enabled.

Thanks!

Comment: what exact error you get when deploying with /32.
People are using 3 digits (100,200,300) and even 4 (1000,2000,3000) to be able to put something in-between if required in future, without having to reorder everything .... it's a common practice ....

Comment: thanks the answer, I have to correct myself, I does deploy with /32 (had other deployment issues). However, I cannot reach the webservice from my website with this /32 permit. Does azure have something else I have to add to my rule?

Comment: What if you disable ACL then have a dummy WS method that just logs/returns the IP of the caller? Then you can call that method from the website and confirm what exact IP is the website presenting to the WS.

Comment: Tried to see what the incoming IP is..took too long with my WCF noob brain and decided to postpone it. Going to try what Petr in his answer below says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP SSL does not guarantee the outbound IP address for outgoing connections, but it only associates the inbound IP with your site. You will need to whitelist all possible outbound IP addresses for your site according to what region your site is in.

For the list of outbound possible IP addresses you can look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd53afb7-14b8-41ca-bfcb-305bdeea413e/maintenance-notice-upcoming-changes-to-increase-capacity-for-outbound-network-calls?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

The reason for this is that Azure Websites is a multitenant environment and the outbound IP address cannot be guaranteed at the site level.

Comment: Gonna give it a try tonight and let you know